# Best language / method for respawning hung processes on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ubuntu, awk

I have an Ubuntu Oneiric server that runs several instances of ffmpeg (each one transcoding a live video feed). From time to time one of the ffmpeg instances will hang. By "hang" I mean the process doesn't end, it just sits there doing nothing. I'm using Upstart to automatically respawn processes that crash, which works OK, but it doesn't detect when a process has hung.

At the CLI I can easily detect which process has hung using "ps axo pid,pcpu,comm | grep ffmpeg". For processes that are not hung, the pcpu value will be > 200, but for a hung one it'll be 100 (or very close to it). In this scenario, I simply have to kill the hung process and Upstart jumps in and respawns it.

I'm fairly new to Linux, so my question is: what's the best technology / language to automate this? I guess what I need to do is parse the output from ps to find instances with pcpu near 100, and then kill those instances.

Thanks.

F

Comment: Could you provide an example of your upstart conf file for launching and respawning ffmpeg, @fishingwiththesleepers ? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing without success... :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buliding on user980473's answer I would probably use awk as well, but instead just returning the PID I would call my command and pipe it to bash. Although, I would remove grep and just use awk and move the conditional statement inside the braces.

`ps axo pid,comm,pcpu| awk '/ffmpeg/ {if ($3 <= 15.0 && $3 >= 10.0) print "kill -9 "$1}' | bash`

notice that my conditional expression is a bit more refined. as user980473's would also print the PIDs greater than 10.0. It appears the working processes of ffmpeg are around 20%? you wouldn't want to kill off those. mine looks at between 10-15%, but that can easily be refined more. You notice `awk` will than print kill -9 $1 to stdout but, with the pipe to bash these calls will be 'hot'.

I am unfamiliar with upstart, but you can more commands. Perhaps you need to call a local python scripit afterwards the command would look virtually the same, but after the $1 you would have "; ./rebootScript.py"

or

`ps axo pid,comm,pcpu| awk '/ffmpeg/ {if ($3 <= 15.0 && $3 >= 10.0) print "kill -9 "$"; ./rebootScript.py"}'`

so this than asks how would you do this? Sitting at the CLI and typing this every 5mins is unresonable. 
this is where I would set up a cron job.

save this file as a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

ps axo pid,comm,pcpu| awk '/ffmpeg/ {if ($3 <= 15.0 && $3 >= 10.0) print "kill -9 "$1}' | bash
```

NEXT, set the correct permissions. `sudo chmod +x ./ffmpegCheck.sh`

and move the script to where you would like to keep it. I would place mine in `mv ffmpegCheck.sh /usr/local/bin/ffmpegcheck`

this would allow me to invoke it by simply calling `ffmpegcheck`

`crontab -l` or `sudo crontab -l` for root will display the current cron file..

it should look something like this

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

you will want to add an entry to the list. I would type `sudo crontab -e` but there are other methods.
and add 
`*/3 * * * * /usr/local/bin/ffmpegcheck # ffmpeg check`

this will run the script every 3 minutes. This can be configured some. Good Luck.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer thanks. I only need to kill the hung process (because Upstart will automatically respawn it) so your first command should do nicely. I notice you moved the decimal point in my pcpu values one place to the left. My values are mostly 3-digit. Running ffmpeg processes are typically in the range 200 - 500. Perhaps this is because my server has more cores than an orchard :) and maybe 100 == 1 full core.

Comment: It seems pcpu value in ps is not a current snapshot, but is instead a historical figure covering the entire period the process has been running. This isn't appropriate for my needs, so I've switched to using the "top" command instead. This seems to do the job just fine: top -b -n 1 | awk '/ffmpeg/ {if ($9 <= 103 && $9 >= 97) print "kill -9 "$1}' | bash

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the *best* technology/language, but awk would work, e.g.

```
$ ps axo pid,comm,pcpu | awk '/ffmpeg/ {if ($3 >= 10.0) print $1}'
```

would give you the PIDs of all ffmpeg processes using more than 10% CPU.

-o

Comment: +1 if you fix the Useless Use of Grep. See http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep

Comment: Sorry about that. I was mostly trying to point fishingwiththesleepers in the right direction, building on what s/he already had. Won't happen again.

Comment: No hard feelings, just trying to help improve your answer. Do you want to edit it, or shall I? (-:

Comment: Since the right way of doing it has been posted, it's not that important, but it's fixed now. Cheers.